# Communication between to Forms of two Project C#

Tags: c#, forms, interface, projects-and-solutions

If two project in an solution ,how to open one of the form from Project 1 through this I go to form of project 2 and how can I go back to previous form in C#??

Comment: You can't have two solutions in a project.

Comment: When you change a value on one form have it put it into a database and then use that in the other form and vice versa

Comment: i assumed you ment 2 projects in 1 solution

Comment: Yes yes  2 project in 1 solution

Comment: As long as you have project references between the 2 projects, you can expose public methods to do what you want.

Comment: and what is use of Add reference, i used to open that form from project 2, and if make both of it,it shows circular dependency error

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project1 in Solution Explorer.
Add -> Reference -> Solution -> [Choose project2 and mark it] -> OK

in project1 make something like this:

```
using project2; //or whatever namespace you have in project2
```

and then call it like that somewhere:

```
FormFromProject2.Show(); //FormFromProject2 is the name of the Form type you want to call
```

Voila!

Comment: i used to open that form from project 2, and if make both of it,it shows circular dependency error

Comment: If you referenced project1 in project2 then you used it somewhere for something. Could you show us what you tried to do?

Comment: I just nothing done yet because i already add reference project 1 in project 2,and i run it and open form 2 from  form1 on button click , and there is a button to call form 2 from from 1,wat code want to give to that button of form2

Comment: if those forms can call each other, why you divided them by different projects??? Just put them in one project and do Form.Show()

Comment: I think dependency can be resolved.both the peoject are from different parents.